# To view the content of .jar file

Tags: java

I do have a .jar file and i need to view the content of the jar files.

1. Is there any decoder available for decoding the jar file.
2. I have the solaris environment also and i need to know what is the

Answer (score 14):

Use the `jar` command line, i.e.

```
jar tf jarfile.jar
```

Comment: **- t**  `list table of contents for archive`  **- f**  `specify archive file name`

Answer (score 10):

unzip it.  It's just a zip file.

Answer (score 3):

Just google **jd-gui**

Hopefully this works for you

Answer (score 1):

The "official" utility is called "jar" and should be installed if a Java environment is installed. It is a command line utility that works similar to the UNIX tool "tar".

But as Mick Sear mentioned, "unzip" will also work.

Answer (score 1):

*.jar are archived files.
Try extracting it with an Archiver!(similar to WinRAR on windows)

Answer (score 0):

JAR files are packaged as zips, so any tools you use to open zip files should work.